# Can Turtlebot2 directly use Octomap to navigate?

Tags: slam, navigation, turtlebot2, octomap, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two questions.
First, in octomap_server,the published topics octomap_binary and octomap_full are the topics for navigation which likes  like grid_map and proj_map.Yes or No. And why.
Secondly, can 2-DOF robot(Turtlebot2) directly use the map above. I means it doesn't need downprojected 2D occupancy map from the 3D map.
wiki.ros.org/octomap_server
wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246368/can-turtlebot2-directly-use-octomap-to-navigate?/) by [Nick Hoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28099/nick-hoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2016-10-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

[move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) uses a 2D occupancy grid map to plan trajectories. The octomap topics are 3D occupancy maps, which would be used by some other 3D planning approach (e.g., [move_it](http://moveit.ros.org/)). They are not the same as `/grid_map` or `/proj_map` from [rtabmap_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros). You should use `/map` output topic of [octomap_server](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_server#Published_Topics) with `move_base`. So for your second question, yes it needs the down projected 2D map.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nick Hoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28099/nick-hoo/) on 2016-10-25**:
Thank you very much.

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2020-12-21**:
Is this the standard way for robot navigation with 3d environment in ros till now? Or is their any other better method?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2020-12-24**:
As long as you can simplify navigation in 2D (even if the terrain is 3D), move_base seems the most ROS way to do that. For 3D trajectories (having to move in Z, e.g., quadcopter), then using OctoMap with OMPL/move_it can be another approach, though not sure if there is one most popular approach for the 3D case.